# I'm trying to make timer and I want to places these 3 buttons in circle

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make stopwatch and I want to put these 3 buttons in a circle but responsive. I have already make a circle that is responsive now I just want to add 3 buttons inside the circle under the timer.

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/obh0mru4/1/

See my result:

[image: See my result]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stop Watch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-5 h-position-relative">
        <div>
            <h1 class="title">Stop Watch</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="circle mt-5">
            <div>
                <h1 id="hour" class="circleContent">00</h1><span class="circleContent-span">:</span>
                <h1 id="min" class="circleContent">00</h1><span class="circleContent-span">:</span>
                <h1 id="sec" class="circleContent">00</h1><span class="circleContent-span">:</span>
                <h1 id="msec" class="circleContent">00</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="h-position-absolute h-tl">
            <button onclick="start()">Start</button>
            <button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
            <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

</html>
```

```
body {
    background: #000428;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #004e92, #000428);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #004e92, #000428);
}

.title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.circle {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    line-height: 320px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 10px solid #666;
    border-style: double;
}

.circleContent {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    width: 60px;
}

.circleContent-span {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
}

.h-position-relative {
    position: relative;
}

.h-position-absolute {
    position: absolute;
}

.h-tl {
    top: smth;
    left: smth;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to fiddle around with the numbers to get exactly what you want, but this is a start:

```css
.h-tl {
    top: 275px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

What it does is place the buttons vertically at 275px.
It also places the left hand side horizontally to the center, but you don't want that so you move it back 50% of it's own width. (This is a common 'trick', you can remove the translate once to see what it exactly does).

This will put your buttons under your digits